# Bootstrap 3: Responsive Table with Floating Header

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to make the table header floating with example from here: http://cmcqueen1975.bitbucket.org/htmlFloatingTableHeader/tables.html. But it doesn't show smooth floating header at IE and Chrome.

So, I tried with another one, http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/. This one shows smooth floating when scrolling in IE, but the column size in the table doesn't show well.

Both method above doesn't work well with Bootstrap responsive table.

Do you know any other method for floating table header that works well with bootstrap 3 responsive table?

Comment: I know it's not excactly what you need.. but check out this [JQuery Plug-in](https://github.com/nheldman/jquery.scrollTableBody)

Comment: I am the author of floatThead - I recently added much better support for ie8 and 9. It should work fine now, just read the readme about using correct meta tags

Comment: Hi. Wow, it's really great to meet the author here. I have just downloaded the minified version from your website. But the file seems identical to the previous one, which I downloaded before. Btw, just to make clearer explanation to you: Once I use floatThread with Bootstrap 3, both table responsive (you can see it when you resize your browser to very small) and the table columns don't display well. You can see the different very clearly by turn on and off floadThread plugin. Thank you.

Comment: If you can make a demo of your issue on jsfiddle and throw a link to it on the project's github issues listing, then I will try to fix it.

Answer (score 12):

I've been looking for something much alike. Because of this question I found  http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/ which I am now using. I don't see any problems as this is the sole solution that actually works for me.

I tried writing my own plugin which worked up until a certain point. Alas it started failing once I put it in a `.table-responsive`. The floatThead plugin does everything I want it to do. Perhaps you used an older version and have bugs been solved now?